# Good OSX development tutorials which do NOT use interface builder?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am an iOS developer. I'm porting an app from iOS to OSX and need some good tutorials to help me get up to speed with OSX coding. This question has been asked a few times, but all the answers reference tutorials which depend heavily on Interface Builder. I do not want to use interface builder (Please don't hijack my question by asking why I don't want to use IB). Ideally I'd like to find some tutorials that assume you already have objective-C/iOS experience.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [Why is asking for references/sources to study specific topics considered not constructive?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153220)

Comment: -1 for *don't hijack my question...* When you're asking for help with doing something in a non-standard way, it's a good idea to offer some explanation of *why* you need to do it that way. People will be more inclined to help you if they understand that you really do have a good reason and you're not just stubborn or uninformed.

Comment: Interface builder is too rigid for my purposes. It also obfuscates what is really going on behind the scenes. The app I am porting is very UI heavy and the UI is all (necessarily) drawn programmatically. For this reason I need to actually understand how UI elements are created in OSX. I didn't mean to come across as rude, I just wanted to avoid the scenario where I get into a long, unrelated argument about the merits (or lack-thereof) of IB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interface buildier for developing OSX is close to essential in my opinion. You are going to waste so much time setting everything up yourself in code. Just remember on iOS you have a single window, and at any one time you have a single view controller on screen (generally). On the Mac this isn't true and not only that you need to think about the menus too.

This do it all yourself mindset is great when you're learning and want to understand all the ins and outs but, it sounds like you are on a real project... I mean, you probably have a deadline. Embrace IB.

If you still want to get a kick start of using cocoa without IB then I think this should be a good read.

http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2007/05/16/working-without-a-nib-part-1/

Comment: It's true that it is a real project and that I do have a deadline, it's also true, however, that I am learning and that to get this app done I will need to understand all the ins and outs. It's not a conventional OSX app. Thanks for this article!

Comment: Good luck, I understand your mentality, and I think that there will come a time you'll really enjoy using the tools (IB... whatever else), I know in the early days these seemed like a bunch of WYSIWYG, and as I coded more, I felt I needed to act more like a "pro" and code everything. Today however I've learnt to embrace these tools. Even UIStoryboard !!! I didn't think that would ever happen ! So, for me I see it as a phase almost every developer goes through, at least the modern ones anyway, I mean there was no such thing to avoid in the 90s really... ;)